# I have corrupted my grub file while trying to disable my gpu

Tags: grub2, radeon

Edit: the issue is now fixed, not sure if im supposed to close the thread or how to do that.

So, I have a really old laptop and my gpu has been overheating like crazy, I tried disabling it. After digging for a couple hours, I found a method on here which suggests to run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and change the line
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` 
to
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"`

I saved it, updated grub, rebooted, and now I get a black screen on boot saying

`[    8.216347] [drm:radeon_module_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No AIMS support in radeon module!`

I have tried some keys suggested by others to access the GRUB file on bootup, but none have worked. Also, should note I am booting from EFI file.

I am running Kubuntu 22.04.1 (Jammy Jellyfish) on an old elitebook laptop.

Update: A live Boot Repair disk failed to solve the problem, and was unable to complete, stopping itself and saying it was cancelled.

Boot info summary: [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9wDQnrhWRv/)

Comment: @guiverc Running 22.04.1 LTS (jammy jellyfish), post updated. Ive also tried repairing it from live usb boot, with no success. Its very weird, as it said installation successful, no errors detected, and now the same error prints twice on boot... Was following this thread, other methods i ran into issues i cannot figure out myself askubuntu.com/questions/1444326

Comment: If you need to change back to default the easiest way may be to just use Boot-Repair's advanced mode with UEFI boot and choose total reinstall of grub & latest kernel. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: "You need to be logged in to view this paste." - No, I won't login. You need to post this log on another platform.

Comment: boot-repair failed to work, what ended up working is i had to boot live usb, did some mounting and chroot i didnt fully understand, and was able to manually edit the grub file from there to revert the changes. Also, is the log not posted on this same platform?